# Cocoapod not being imported during build for test target

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'll preface this by saying that the solution is probably very simple but I've tried for hours to figure this out and I feel like it's close, but something is still wrong.

I'm creating a Cocoapod that has some other pods as dependencies and I'm trying to setup the projects / targets to work but running into the problem where the Cocoapod dependencies that I'm trying to load in `PusherSwift.swift` (`import Alamofire` etc) are failing.

Here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/hamchapman/pusher-swift-test

Can anyone see why the pod frameworks aren't being loaded so that they can be used in the `PusherSwift.swift` file?

Specifically I'm trying to run the (default) tests but it keeps on failing saying:

`No such module Alamofire`

Note, I'm using the following:

- cocoapods 0.36.0 beta2 gem
- Xcode 6.3 beta

Comment: Is swift support stable yet?

Comment: Well I'm assuming not completely seeing as the gem is still a beta. However, I feel like the problem I've got is something trivial (when you know the answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay well I have made it work now by adding the Pods project inside the PusherSwift project. I'm not entirely sure why that made it work but it basically just seemed to make the frameworks available to the PusherSwift targets.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
target 'Echo' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'Google/AppInvite'
    pod 'Appirater'
    pod 'FDTake'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'TDBadgedCell'
    pod 'FDWaveformView'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'

    target 'EchoTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end
```

This makes it so that the test target has all the pods that the main target has, but you're still able to define some testdependencies like mocking or stubbing pods

Answer (score 1):

By default Cocoapods only links to the first target in your project. The second target, which is usually your unit tests, is not linked.
http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#link_with

Use the `link_with` config in your Podfile to explicitly link pods to your unit tests target. eg

`link_with 'MyApp', 'MyAppTests'`

Comment: Is there a similar solution for cocoapods 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

This is a stupid answer but it works.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Echo' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'Google/AppInvite'
    pod 'Appirater'
    pod 'FDTake'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'TDBadgedCell'
    pod 'FDWaveformView'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end

target 'EchoTests' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'Google/AppInvite'
    pod 'Appirater'
    pod 'FDTake'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'TDBadgedCell'
    pod 'FDWaveformView'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I can't find it!